# Do Spring Security 5 Authorization supports resource owner grant

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

We are trying to build application for Mobile and web
react-native and react js respectively.

As we see legacy spring-security-oauth is deprecated, we would like to use spring authorization server 5 project

Do this authorization server project supports Password Grant, as we have challenges in doing Authorization code grant for custom login Authentication like biometric

Answer (score 1):

The `Spring Authorization Server` does not support authorization grant type `PASSWORD`. This project is mainly focused to deliver the Authorization server as per the latest `OAuth 2.0` security practices in which the use of `Resource Owner Password Credentials` grant is disallowed.